# Unable to copy file, Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, azure-pipelines, culture

My site has localization (multi-language)

I use ASP.NET resource files for each culture, such as:

- Controllers.UserProfileController.en-ca.resx
- Controllers.UserProfileController.es-us.resx
- Controllers.UserProfileController.pt-br.resx

and etc..

I also have this line in Startup.cs

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "ResourcesDirectoryFolderName");
```

When I build and publish the site, in bin folder it is creating a folder for each culture, such as:

- C:\User\Documents\SchoolApp\School.API\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\en-ca
- C:\User\Documents\SchoolApp\School.API\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\es-us
- C:\User\Documents\SchoolApp\School.API\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\pt-BR

In each folder, I have some DLL files. Which is fine.

Problem comes when I use Azure pipelines to compile/build/publish the app (CI/CD). It is throwing error:

> ##[error] /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4364,5):
> Error MSB3021: Unable to copy file
> "/home/vsts/work/1/s/School.Services/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/pt-br/School.Services.resources.dll"
> to "bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/pt-br/School.Services.resources.dll".
> Could not find a part of the path
> '/home/vsts/work/1/s/School.API/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/pt-br/School.Services.resources.dll'.

All if fine on local. I am not getting error when I build or publish on my localhost. This is happening on Azure Pipelines.

This is happening only for `pt-br`. For other cultures I am not getting an error. Before adding `pt-br` I was not getting any error.

Notice that `pt-br` (lowercase) is used in resource file name, but when folder generated inside bin folder it is names as `pt-BR` (uppercase BR). Could this case sensitivity be the problem? Maybe when copying the files Azure Pipelines is looking for folder name `pt-br` but actually the system generated folder name `pt-BR`? Why other cultures are not encountering this problem, but only `pt-br`?

I followed instuctions at here to build my multi language app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1

How can I fix it?

Comment: Hi, how about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question, If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Could this case sensitivity be the problem?

The copy-related commands in Linux are case-sensitive. (You're running the pipeline in Ubuntu machine). So I agree that `case sensitivity` could be the problem.

It looks like your `School.API` project depends on `School.Services` project, so you need to check these two projects for why the folder is generated as `pt-BR`.

You should check project files and the resource files of these two projects. Also, as a quick workaround I suggest you can rename your resource file to `Controllers.UserProfileController.pt-BR.resx`. See [Supported Culture Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/common-parameters-and-types/supported-culture-codes)
,the `pt-BR` is the original format that represents `Portuguese (Brazil)`.